# is there a way to see how many pages is on my website that's created each month on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a pretty big website, and I'm wondering if google analytics api allows me to look at how many pages were made per month. Or rather, a list of sites that were made with a date tag, that way I can transform it into a count.

Comment: You can only capture information via GA about pages that have actually been visited - anything that is on your website but not visited will be invisible to your GA stats. So I am afraid the answer is probably No, unless you /know/ that every new page will be visited at least once. Obviously, also, each new page must be GA-enabled. But, if you get past those hurdles, then you should be able to count your pages using, for example, Google Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

No, GA will only provide you with information based on visits, if pages were created and no one visits them, then that page will be missing. Plus you're looking at this MoM, if all of your pages don't get visited during a month, then they will be missing as well. Your best bet is to use a site crawler to index all of your pages.

If you really want to capture this in GA, then consider triggering a GA event when pages are created, this is assuming the creation process is via a web interface (wordpress for example).

Comment: Yes. Event tracking is probably the way to go, but even then there are creation date, published date, and revised date, etc. OP is probably better off pulling the data directly from the CMS as tracking these via GA events would probably get very messy.